# Carriage return and 0 character

Tags: c++, return

I have a problem, because as a Junior Programmer in C++ I was going to do some practice and I got stuck on a `cout << "0\r";` problem. Why does `\r` ignore 0? I've searched throughout the whole Internet, but I haven't found any answer for that question... It's important for me, because `\r` leaves unnecessarily the rubbish zeros on the way it's working :/

Which other way can I delete all the chars from the line the carriage is currently on, and remove the zeros?

PS. I use Dev-C++ IDE.

Comment: Explain more clearly what you are seeing and what you expect to see. I don't know what you mean by "\r ignore 0" or "rubbish zeros".

Comment: For example, if in the first line I write 10203040 and then \r, the zeros don't leave - I can see 0000, and the 1234 disappear, but why only 1234?..

Comment: I still don't understand. Post a *small* but *complete* program that shows the problem.

Comment: @user3477729  I'm not sure what are you talking about. I also use devCPP and I have no problem with the line of code, `cout<<"10203040\r;"` It perfectly prints `10203040` with the cursor blinking on `1`..
Could you be more specific and provide some edit on your post, like sample code and sample output to your problem??

Comment: http://pastebin.com/t6pKA2y0

Comment: backslash r deletes the characters from the current line, doesn't it?

Comment: Oh, thanks HolyBlackCat, looks like it's me who hasn't understood how backslash r works, lol at me x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, `std::cout << "10203040\r";` prints `10203040`. `'\r'` itself doesn't remove any characters; it just moves the cursor to the first symbol of the line. If you want to erase something, you should print spaces like this:

```
std::cout <<   "Random text.";
std::cout << "\r            \r";
```

Comment: also you can use `cout << "\r\t\r";`

Answer (score 0):

`\r` returns the cursor to the first position of the **same line**. So you don't see the character `0`.